# Print Dialog in servlet/jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, printdialog

I want to display print dialog in servlet/jsp. Below is my code:

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet () ;
PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
PrintService service = javax.print.ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

if (service != null)
{
  DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(decodedImageData, flavor, null);
  job.print(doc, null);
}
```

It works well in a standalone application. However, I am not able to display print dialog in servlet/jsp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that it is not the client that is executing your code here. It's the server.

You'll have to make a javascript function for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would call `window.print();` in javascript. Try it below.

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="javascript:print()">Print</a>
</body>

</html>
```